# How can I define a sequence of functions?

Tags: functions, recursion

I need to define a function `fun`, and then re-define this function iteratively. The code is given at the end.

First, a function `fun[x_, y_, d_]` is defined, which is a polynomial in $x$ and $y$, and $d$ is the degree of this polynomial.

My goal is to modify `fun` according to some of its coefficients, see the definition `fun2[x_, y_, d_]` for example.

The problem is that, these coefficients are $0$ if $d$ is not substituted by a "real" number, like $d = 1$. See the code between the definitions of `fun` and `fun2`.

Just after the definition of `fun2`, I compute `fun2[x, y, d]` and it is the same as `fun1[x, y, d]`. The reason is that $d$ is not assigned a value. But `fun2[x, y, 1]` gives the desired answer, which is different from `fun[x, y, 1]`.

The problem is that I want to repeat this process many times, say

```
fun3 = fun2 + Coefficient[fun2, x^2]
fun4 = fun3 + Coefficient[fun3, x^3]
....
fun"d" = fun2 + Coefficient[fun"d-1", x^(d-1)]
```

(This is just an example, the real process I need is far more complicated and can not be deined in one go. In this example, one can just use `Sum[Coefficient...]`.)

Of course I don't want introduce so many functions. I want to define  `fun` and modify it in a for loop. But the code below shows that `Coefficient[fun[x, y, d], ...]` is always $0$, since $d$ is not assigned a value.

I can't use a variable like `temp` in this for loop, because

```
For [i =...
  ....
  temp = fun[x, y, d]
  temp = temp + Coefficient[temp, x^i]
  ...
```

will just give `fun[x, y, d]`, as `Coefficient[temp, x^i]` is always $0$ as mentioned above.

***I need a suggestion on how to do such work more elegantly.***

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Having code that can be pasted into a notebook makes it more likely that users will try to help.  To convert the sigma notation to `Sum`, you can "Convert To > InputForm" from the "Cell" menus before copying, if that's a problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
fun[n_Integer?Positive][x_, y_, d_Integer] := 
  fun[n - 1][x, y, d] + Coefficient[fun[n - 1][x, y, d], x, n - 1 ];
fun[0][x_, y_, d_Integer] := 
  Sum[(i + j) x^i y^j Subscript[a, i, j], {i, d}, {j, d}];
Table[fun[n][x, y, 1], {n, 0, 2}] // TableForm
```

Comment: You might want some pattern restrictions, to prevent evaluation in cases where `d` is just the symbol `d`:  E.g., `fun[n_Integer?Positive][x_, y_, d_Integer] :=...`

Comment: @MichaelE2 updated code to include your suggestion.

Comment: @Hecotr, thanks. It works. By the way, do you know if there is a more sophisticated way to define recursive functions, like a C programming. For example  `f[x_,n_]:= { exp1; exp2; exp3; return f[x,n-1]+exp3 }`?

Comment: @user565739, "Sophisticated" is in the eye of the beholder … faster might be a better metric. In any case, the following code might satisfy you: `f[x_, n_Integer?Positive] := g[f[x, n - 1]]`

Answer (score 1):

Another way (using same definition of f[x,y,d]:

```
  nestpol[n_Integer, d_Integer] := 
     NestList[{#[[1]] + 1, #[[2]] + Coefficient[#[[2]], x^(#[[1]])]} &, 
{1, f[x, y, d]}, n][[;; , 2]]
```

note
(i) if just want the last value just change NestList to Nest
(ii) in Hector's answer (based on no constant term in polynomial) f[0][x,y,d]=f[1][x,y.d], so nestpol[N,d] yields the same result as Table[fun[n][x, y, 1], {n, 1,N}]